# Examples of Wear OS development for use with iPhone/iOS

Tags: wear-os

I am really struggling to find any references on developing WearOS apps using an iPhone. I see references in the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating#iphone-companion), but have not been able to find any examples or code online. I now companies like [Cardieo](https://cardieo.com/product/cardieo-smart-watch-3v?gclid=CjwKCAiA8Jf-BRB-EiwAWDtEGrz5xR6GqLvadWyq3fteFj7cFZYsoD_VT_7X6l9S_1_AI6EN42iq3hoClMQQAvD_BwE) have mentioned they developed on Wear OS and have an iOS app. Does anybody have any good sample code to use as an example?